# Creating multiple lists from dict?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have data like this:

`d = [{"name":"Matt", "age":10, "state":"NJ"}, {"name":"Jack", "age":8, "state":"NY"}]`

I want three separate lists:`names, ages, states`

Here is one way to do that:

```
names = [e['name'] for e in d]
ages =  [e['age'] for e in d]
states =  [e['state'] for e in d]
```

But that requires going through `d` 3 times.

Can I do it all in one swoop without a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can:

```
names, ages, states = [[e[name] for e in d] for name in ('name', 'age', 'state')]
```

assuming that by *without a `for` loop* you actually mean *with list-comprehensions*.

---

With Python primitives only, you would need to do a nested-loop one way or another.
However, the data you describe seem to fit well the *tabular* model.
If you find yourself doing *tabular* operations often, you may be better off using a specialized tool like `pandas`, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd


d = [{"name":"Matt", "age":10, "state":"NJ"}, {"name":"Jack", "age":8, "state":"NY"}]

df = pd.Dataframe(d)
#    age  name state
# 0   10  Matt    NJ
# 1    8  Jack    NY

df['name']
# 0    Matt
# 1    Jack
# Name: name, dtype: object
```

---

Note that merely not seeing the word `for` does not mean you are actually not looping.
Consider, for example the following:

```
d = [{"name":"Matt", "age":10, "state":"NJ"}, {"name":"Jack", "age":8, "state":"NY"}]
l = [list(x.values()) for x in d]
# [['Matt', 10, 'NJ'], ['Jack', 8, 'NY']]
names, ages, states = list(zip(*l))
```

Here, although there is only one *explicit* looping through `d`, you are actually having an extra loop *hidden* in the `list()` creation.
Another *hidden* looping goes with the `*` magic.
Hence, with the above code, you are actually looping through your dataset 2 times with 2 nested-loops each time.
Granted that these hidden loop are typically faster, for large enough datasets, this solution will be slower than the one-liner from above.

In my system, for `d` as it is, they are about the same speed:

```
dd = d * 1
%timeit names, ages, states = [[e[name] for e in dd] for name in ('name', 'age', 'state')]
# 1.45 µs ± 9.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit l = [list(x.values()) for x in dd]; names, ages, states = list(zip(*l))
# 1.47 µs ± 19.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

but for `d` 10 times bigger, the one-liner is already approx. twice as fast:

```
dd = d * 10
%timeit names, ages, states = [[e[name] for e in dd] for name in ('name', 'age', 'state')]
# 4.14 µs ± 219 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit l = [list(x.values()) for x in dd]; names, ages, states = list(zip(*l))
# 8.01 µs ± 79.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Finally note that if you have control over how the data is generated, if you have a list of lists like `l`, then the *implicit* looping of `list(zip(*l))` will be faster than the equivalent nested list comprehension.

Comment: You cannot help but have 6 iterations, whatever angle you pick. But if you change the order of the comprehension you have the transposed result.

Comment: @Tomerikoo the problem is that you have `[[f(a, c) for a in b] for c in d]` but the nested `[]` will make `[[f(a, c) for c in d] for a in b]` one the transpose of the other. So you cannot really swap the two loops if you want to end up with the indicated lists.

Answer (score 0):

this go through `d` only one time, just not elegant :

```py
names, ages, states = [], [], []
for e in d:
    names.append(e['name'])
    ages.append(e['age'])
    states.append(e['state'])
```